# SVN Endless Loop - [file] "does not exist in repository"

Tags: tortoisesvn

This has been plaguing me for a week.

SVN keeps telling me that a certain file "`does not exist in repository`".

Fine.  Let's just delete it.  Forget about it.  Ignore it.  Whatever.  I don't really care about this file (especially if it continues to fail the nightly check-in).

The most bizarre part?  A "restore" will actually RESTORE the file from the repository, so its there (corrupted, maybe?).

...and this has to be the icing on the cake.  If I delete the file through Windows Explorer, SVN will RESTORE the file from the repository, and right after that state that it doesn't exist in the repository.  WTF?

Does anyone have a clue how to get rid of this?

I've already tried clean-ups, reversions, deletions and anything else imaginable, but this one has me stumped.

Thanks for any tips you might have...

Comment: Did you try to `svn rename` that file (to remove the '^')? And then commit, then delete (and recommit)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems most likely that you have corrupted your local working copy, e.g. by moving folders or some other manipulation that you did with windows explorer but should have done through the TortoiseSVN context menu. The information inside the `.svn` folders now no longer matches the state of the working copy, which is confusing Subversion.

To fix this, delete the parent folder ("Originals") in your working copy with windows explorer (NOT with TortoiseSVN). Then do a TortoiseSVN "update" at the root of your working copy. This should restore the folder in working order.

Another option is to discard your working copy entirely and do a fresh checkout.

Note that the next release of Subversion (1.7) will reduce the opportunities for corrupting your working copy by centralizing all metadata in a single `.svn` folder at the root.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a common situation. The working copy can get corrupted (yet remain coherent) and there's no way to find out. Fresh checkout is the only reliable fix.

Comment: Hi Wim - Your first suggestion did the trick.  Thanks!  Oh, and great news about 1.7 trying to minimize some of this.  SVN 1.6 is a little too unforgiving about minor mistakes.

Comment: Hoping there's another way... Deleting the enclosing folder is not an option for me :(

Comment: @jowie: naturally you don't have to destroy your work which is inside that folder. It's just the .svn folders which are corrupted. So make a copy of the corrupted folder, remove any `.svn` folders in that copy, now fix the original with a delete+update to repair the .svn metadata, and finally copy your work back over the fixed folder. And please upgrade to svn/tortoisesvn 1.7!

Comment: @WimCoenen - unfortunately it is part of a shared Xcode project and has 100s of MBs of files inside it. Xcode is notoriously bad for file references... If I create an entirely new folder and delete the old one I foresee many horrible issues!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with corrupted working copies.  Sometimes the working copies have a lot of pending changes but unable to checkin.  To resolve this, I use the following approach (svn 1.7+):

1. Checkout a fresh working copy into a new directory (path2)
2. In the fresh working copy, if the offending file is there, delete it if needed.
3. Commit the fresh working copy
4. In the fresh working copy, delete everything except the .svn directory
5. Copy everything from the old working copy except the .svn directory into the fresh working copy.
6. Commit the fresh working copy again
7. Delete (or backup) the old working copy
8. Rename the fresh working to the old working copy (path2 to path)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar problem wherein i had a folder, for example "FolderA" which consistently shows in svn update even though I had deleted it.
It would not even show in the folder list but svn would still recognise it as if it exists.

I followed below steps:

1.Create same folder name for which svn was giving error in the same file location
2.Added it to svn checkout. Since it gave conflict errors, i resolved it using the svn option to resolve.
3.Deleted the folder and committed my svn.

Error was resolved