# TortoiseSVN error "Commit failed. File is out of date"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I have made several attempts to delete/unversion a file using TortoiseSVN and every time I try to commit the changes, I end up with the same error.

```
Commit failed (details follow): '/trunk/lib/Web.Debug.config' is out of date.
You have to update your working copy first.
```

Updating the file/folder completes without errors. Using repo-browser i have verified that the file exists only in the local copy. Deleting using **Extended Context Menu → Delete (keep local)** and committing still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion will not allow you to commit a change to an item unless your working copy knows about the state of the latest revision of the item. The message you're getting is telling you that you're attempting an operation on an item which may or may not exist anymore in the repository, or may have been changed since you last checked with the repository. As a result, it won't let you continue because there's no way of verifying that what you're going to commit is correct/valid - you can't commit a change to something that doesn't exist in the repository.

Comment: So how can i delete/un-version the file and prevent tortoisesvn showing it as a versioned item?

Comment: You really have to update the file first. Since you are going to delete the file anyway, you can just undo/revert your change (the deletion), update the file to the latest revision and then redo the deletion thru `svn remove` or thru an IDE.

Comment: That's what i have repeatedly been doing. Revert/update and then trying to remove it from the repository but always returning the error. The file only exists in local working copy and not main repository.

Comment: Move the file to another directory, run SVN Update, then move it back.

Comment: Moving the file sounds a viable solution. However, resolved the issue as follows: Created similar file in repository and updated. This resulted in `skipped obstructing working copy` and warning 
`One or more files are in a conflicted state.` Deleted folder with problematic file. Updating resulted in `working copy path does not exist in repository`. Reading [SVN Endless Loop...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591015/svn-endless-loop-file-does-not-exist-in-repository), I realized I had moved some folders around. Opted to discard working copy entirely and do a fresh checkout.